# Why am I getting a stack overflow exception when C# conditional operator?

Tags: c#

This code is causing a stack overflow exception and I'm not sure why.

```
public double? Value
    {
        get
        {
            return Value.HasValue ? (double?)Math.Round(Value.Value, 1) : null;
        }
        set
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your backing variable?

Comment: You need a backing field for the property. It is calling itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your `Get` you are reading the property, causing an infinite loop. Use a backing field.

```
private double? _value;
public double? Value
{
    get { return _value.HasValue ? (double?) Math.Round(_value.Value, 1) : null; }
    set { _value = value; }
}
```

EDIT: I would also like to point out that it's pretty easy to make the case that this is pretty bad code. For one thing, exposing public setters is kind of iffy to begin with, it's only a little better than having a public field. Also, it's really confusing to work with code where you can assign one thing to a variable, but if you inspect it on the line after, the value has changed. I would consider moving the rounding logic into the setter, removing the nullability (if applicable), removing the mutability altogether (again, if applicable) and injecting the value in the constructor.

Comment: It's a ViewModel, I think it's standard practice to have public Properties with getters and setters in a ViewModel. 

Also I think the rounding error is coming from the server.

You set it as 7.6 and it'll return 7.59999...some other values.

Comment: @LeighCooper - You should use `decimal` then.

Comment: I agree with Martin, if the datatype won't cut it, use another. While I concede that setters are more acceptable in a viewmodel, I still think it's Evil(tm) to transform values in the getter, partly because it's confusing to clients, and partly because the code gets run every time you get the value instead of only once when you assign it.

Comment: The values are being stored in a Redis server as a Timeseries. When assigning (throught Setter) 5.6 or similar value, they're being changed to something like 5.599999234 by the server. Therefore as a front end developer, it's difficult for me to change the structure of the data. Generally this ViewModel's value is being set from a timeseries conversion. 

Why would decimal be better?

Answer (score 2):

Because in the setter you are assigning a value to the setter which means the setter is called again. The setter calls itself all the time hence the stackoverflow exception. The same also for the getter.

You should have a real variable to store the value:

```
public double? Value
{
    get
    {
       return myValue.HasValue ? (double?)Math.Round(myValue.Value, 1) : null;
    }
    set
    {
       myValue = value;
    }
}

private double? myValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's an issue with your property:

You have to use a **backing field**, otherwise you won't be able to store/get your value.

Your code becomes:

```
private double? _value;
public double? Value
{
    get
    {
        return _value.HasValue ? (double?)Math.Round(_value.Value, 1) : null;
    }
    set
    {
       _value = value;
    }
}
```

You exception will go away.

Your stack overflow exception comes from Math.Round(Value.Value, 1).

You're trying to get the value of your property. So, you're calling your getter to have this value. Then, you hit **again** the same line, and calls again Math.Round(Value.Value, 1).

Then, it calls again the getter, then...
You see the point.